# After inserting data Cannot forward after response has been committed

Tags: java, servlets

"Here is code after inserting data its cannot forwarding the index page please help me.....
and after that i am not able to fetch data also...
"
'

```
public class insertData extends HttpServlet {

String query;

static Connection conn;
//Statement st;
PreparedStatement pst;
ResultSet res;
ConnectionManager dbconn;

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {

        dbconn= new ConnectionManager();

        String id=request.getParameter("id");
        String fname=request.getParameter("fname");
        String lname=request.getParameter("lname");
        String pass=request.getParameter("pass");
        String mobile=request.getParameter("mbl");
        String email=request.getParameter("email");


        conn=dbconn.getConnection();
         //pst=conn.createStatement();
        pst=conn.prepareStatement ("INSERT INTO reg(`id`, `fname`, `lname`, `pass`, `mbl`, `email`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
       // query="insert into reg(id('"+id+"','"+fname+"','"+lname+"','"+pass+"','"+mobile+"','"+email+"')";
        pst.setString(1, id);
        pst.setString(2, fname);
        pst.setString(3, lname);
        pst.setString(4, pass);
        pst.setString(5, mobile);
        pst.setString(6,email);

        int i=pst.executeUpdate();



    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
      //System.out.println("Exception"+e.getMessage());
      request.setAttribute("Error",e);
      RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/error.jsp");
      rd.forward(request, response);

    }
    finally
    {
        RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);


    }
}
```

'

so......how can i fix this please help me...thanks in advance for help

Comment: Try closing `out` as `out.close()` at the end of the `try` block.

Comment: Thanks For response but still.getting this....Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[insertData]: Servlet.service() for servlet insertData threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:448)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:428)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)
 at insertData.processRequest(insertData.java:66)
 at insertData.doGet(insertData.java:84)

Comment: Are facing any error? If so, please post the stacktrace

Comment: You should declare variables ```con```, ```pst``` and ```dbconn``` in the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an exception occur as per above code it will forward the request using `RequestDispatcher` to error.jsp. Once this happen your **Request is committed and now you cant do anything more with it**.

But you have a `finally` block - *which will get executed irrespective of the fact try block being successful or throwing an exception.* You are again trying to get an `RequestDispatcher` there and forward to index.jsp and hence getting the above error.

Not sure of your exact use case but feel you can redirect to your `index.jsp` as last step of `Try` block itself.And remove the finally block altogether.

One more thing to note is its not advised to write your JDBC/DB related code in `Servlet` itself you can create a separate `DAO` class for that and it will lead to better abstraction and modularity.